# OpenIdDict external login, how to refresh token

Tags: .net, oauth, openid-connect, openiddict

I need to refresh external login access_token, how can I do this?

I have an google external authorization. I need to store AccessToken in HttpContext to make requests into google, but after expiring I need refresh this token.

Answer (score -1):

This is a a sample of how to enable the refresh token flow:

https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Imynusoph

This tutorial also uses refresh tokens:

https://dev.to/robinvanderknaap/setting-up-an-authorization-server-with-openiddict-part-vi-refresh-tokens-5669

1. Allow the flow

```c
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict().AddCore(options =>
{
    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<FaDbContext>();
})
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options
            .AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
            .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
            .AllowPasswordFlow()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
});
```

2. Add the grants to the client

```c
using FaID.Context;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;


namespace FaID.Services.AuthorizationServer
{
    public class TestData : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public TestData(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FaDbContext>();
            await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync(cancellationToken);

            var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictApplicationManager>();

            if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("postman", cancellationToken) is null)
            {
                await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
                {
                    ClientId = "postman",
                    ClientSecret = "postman-secret",
                    DisplayName = "Postman",
                    RedirectUris = { new Uri("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback") },
                    Permissions =
                    {
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,

                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.Password,

                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "api",
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code
                    }
                    ,
                    Type = OpenIddictConstants.ClientTypes.Public
                }, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```